# Gitlab error 502 when loading... is that normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, proxy, timeout, gitlab

When I restart my gitlab server with `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` (Debian Jessie), while the server is loading, I get the 502 error, instead of the "Deploying" page. Then everything works fine. I don't understand why this happens.

[image: Error that I get when the server is loading]

**Please be aware that this appears only when loading, then everything works fine. I'm not satisfied because I used to get the better "Deploying" page.**

This started happening after I configured my gitlab to work through gitlab-workhorse to go through my apache server proxy (prior to that I had huge problems with web interface communication. Snapshots downloads didn't work, but now everything is fine). Before fixing that, I used to proxy gitlab's nginx.

The configuration I currently use for apache is the following, which complies to the [standard configuration of Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-ssl-apache24.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName git.example.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  # Ensure that encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
  # http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#get-single-project
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    # New authorization commands for apache 2.4 and up
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access
    Require all granted

    #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8283
    ProxyPassReverse https://git.example.com/

  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on

  #Don't escape encoded characters in api requests
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8283%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8283%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]


  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  #Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

  #... ssl config

  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog  /home/myuser/logs/gitlab_error.log
  CustomLog /home/myuser/logs/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /home/myuser/logs/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /home/myuser/logs/gitlab.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The only configuration I changed, is my `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, which I did for the proxy to work.

```
external_url 'https://git.example.com'
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8283"
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong to get that 502 error instead of the nice "Deploying" page that I used to get before doing these changes?

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I see  this page after `gitlab-ctl start`.

**My Solution is**

```
sudo gitlab-ctl start

sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

refresh browser :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically this is the way it should work, it's a 502 error after all. If you want to show the deploy page there is a manual way to set it up before each restart:

```
gitlab-ctl deploy-page up
```

Wait a minute and then again:

```
gitlab-ctl deploy-page down
```

Otherwise you can add to your Apache config:

```
ErrorDocument 502 /deploy.html
```

which will show the deploy page every time a 502 error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you telling me that the deploying page is not the standard way to see stuff when the server is restarted? I would wonder then why it was initially like that before I fixed that problem.

Comment: AFAIK, the deploy page was something manually put up when a deploy was at place. If the unicorn server is restarted, then NGINX cannot forward requests to it and it displays a 502.

Answer (score 0):

config server firewall to allow http and https:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
sudo ufw status


Output
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```